# XMLVM Android to iPhone Errors

Tags: android, iphone, xml, virtual-machine, code-conversion

The conversion of my Android application to the iPhone ObjectX environment as described in the XMLVM user manual works almost fine on my MAC, but I end up with 3 errors in the resulting XCode:

The first two errors simply relate to missing files, namely:

```
org_w3c_dom_Node.h
android_app_DatePickerDialog_OnDateSetListener.h
```

These are clearly not files from the converted Android application. Where can I get these from?

The third is an error that keeps coming up in the file

```
java_lang_String.h
```

The error message is:

> typedef NSMutableString java_lang_String: redefinition as different kind of symbol

This error has been reported before in the XMLVM user group but as far as I know has never been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

About the first error:
this is part of the Android API that has not yet been implemented.
This is the reason why it can't find the files.

Now, the second problem is not actually an error, but a warning and shouldn't stop you form compiling. 
If it does, it means that in your project you have set the option to make errors from these types of warnings.
You can safely turn this off and completely ignore this warning.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that this is true for Spinners and the llike, too. Pretty basic stuff that's not supported.